# Calculate a CDF given two PDFs.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have two PDF's, $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ and I need to find the CDF (not PDF) of $f_3(x)$ where

$f_3(x) = \frac{1}{2} (f_1(x) + f_2(x))$

I have already calculated $F_1$ and $ F_2$, the CDF's of $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively.

Can I simply take half the sum of the two CDF's as follows

$F_3(x) = \frac{1}{2}( F_1(x) + F_2(x))$

or do I instead need to compute $f_3$ and then calculate $F_3$ from there?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pdf and cdf are  related by $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$.

In your case
\begin{eqnarray}
F_3(x) &=& \int_{-\infty}^x f_3(t) dt  \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{2}(f_1(t)+f_2(t)) dt \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left(\int_{-\infty}^x f_1(t) dt + \int_{-\infty}^x f_2(t) dt \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} (F_1(x) + F_2(x))
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take the average of the CDF's, because the CDF is found by taking an integral, which is  a linear operator.  Scale factors like $1/2$ can "go outside the integral sign", and so can summation.

If we have some integral transform $T$ such that $T(f(x))$ takes some integral over $f(x)$ to produce another function $F(x)$, it will be a linear operator. This means that you can rely on equivalences such as $T(g(x) + h(x)) = T(g(x)) + T(h(x))$ and $T(C\cdot g(x)) = c\cdot T(g(x))$.